# CardDAV password not saved in Thunderbird, not connecting to remote address book

Tags: thunderbird, contacts, address-book, carddav

I am following the guide to connect Zoho Contacts CardDAV to Thunderbird 102.1.2 (64-bit) address book: https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/zoho-contacts/articles/carddav-11-5-2021#CardDAV_for_Windows

The problems are:

1. the remote address book does not get connected in Thunderbird
2. the password does not get saved in Thunderbird's password manager

The Error Console shows the error "Can't add a login without a httpRealm or formActionOrigin.".

[image]

A similar problem is reported on a forum: https://www-thunderbird--mail-de.translate.goog/forum/thread/83446-lightning-caldav-passwort-wird-nicht-gespeichert/?_x_tr_sl=de&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc

And each time Thunderbird is started, it prompts for the account password to connect to Zoho contacts, even though the box is check for "Use Password Manager to remember this password."

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Thunderbird, which you may signal to the developers.

The problem is explained in the article
[CalDAV and CardDAV functionality is broken for clients which require an `RFC7617` compliant `WWW-Authenticate` header](https://github.com/monicahq/monica/issues/6183)
from 2022-06-11:

> CalDAV and CarDAV functionality is broken for clients which require an RFC7617 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7617#section-2) compliant `WWW-Authenticate` header; specifically, in my case, Thunderbird, which will refuse to save credentials (very similarly to the other commonly searched issue along these lines, ie: https://help.nextcloud.com/t/thunderbird-dont-save-caldav-password-because-of-missing-httprealm-or-formsubmiturl/93233 , albeit that issue is based on needing to return `302 https://$host/dav`; for `/.well-known/carddav` and `/.well-known/caldav` at the proxy, and potentially needing `calendar.network.multirealm = true` overridden within Thunderbird's configuration), which results in a successful first sync, followed by being required to enter credentials for monica's calendar/tasks/contacts syncing on every subsequent launch of Thunderbird. In the case of Thunderbird, the error is silent masked, if not launched in a manner capturing the stdout/stderr, but is: `Can't add a login without a httpRealm or formActionOrigin.`.

So you could try setting `calendar.network.multirealm` to True in
Preferences, scroll down to the bottom and click on the "Config Editor ..."
button. Enter `calendar.network.multirealm` in the selection field
and double-click it. Restart Thunderbird.

However, it's doubtful if this would totally solve the problem of asking
again and again for credentials.

Comment: I tried `calendar.network.multirealm = true` but it seems to make no difference. Also note that CardDAV remote address book connection is working fine in Thunderbird for multiple Gmail accounts. It's not clear to me if the bug is with Thunderbird, or the (Zoho, etc) server side implementation, or both.

Comment: The problem might be with the server not returning a WWW-Authenticate header that Thunderbird can accept, going by the above source.

Comment: The above source leads me to think it is a server not respecting RFC7617 which some clients expect. I emailed Zoho support a couple of weeks ago but haven't received a reply. Not seeing any solution other than disabling CardDAV connection for that account, which isn't really a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Cardbook extension for Thunderbird does correctly store the password and sync the contact. It's more robust than the built in address books as well. I haven't found anything that works better for the calendar yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1160591)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, but at least it provides a workaround. Thanks! I plan to try Cardbook in general, though it would be nice to have instructions on how to use it specifically for this purpose too.